# Adding a WMF to a PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am completely unable to get a WMF file onto a PDF using iTextSharp. I specifically want to use WMF because it is a vector based file.

My WMF file is coming from a [Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.aspx) control.

The code to reproduce this is Very Easy.

1. Create a new Windows Form project.
2. Add a Chart control onto Form1.
3. Then add the below code:

Add this using directive

```
using iTS = iTextSharp.text;
```

And add the below code to your Form1.cs file:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Document pdfDoc = new Document();
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(@"D:\dev\Test\TestPdfCreation\TestPdfCreation\bin\Debug\test.pdf", FileMode.Create));

    MemoryStream mimg1 = new MemoryStream();
    chart1.SaveImage(mimg1, ImageFormat.Wmf);
    mimg1.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    iTS.Image img1 = iTS.Image.GetInstance(mimg1);
    pdfDoc.Add(img1);
    pdfDoc.Close();
}
```

The error I receive is: 
    IOException occurred. The byte array is not a recognized image format.

Using iTextSharp 5.0.5.

Comment: I'm using a WMF file without any problems but I'm loading it from disk. Can you write it to disk and load it by path just to see if that works? I'm wondering if there's an issue with the memory stream.

Comment: Looking a little further there appears to be two different types of WMF files. There's the Windows 3.0 version that has `01 00 09 00 00 03` or `02 00 09 00 00 03` as the first six bytes. But when I make a WMF from Adobe Illustrator I get `D7 CD C6 9A` as the first 4 bytes. The latter is what works for me with iTextSharp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try building it directly rather than calling createImage:

```
Image img = new ImgWMF( bytes );
```

Though looking at the code I see that you'll just get a different exception:

```
        InputMeta in = new InputMeta(is);
        if (in.readInt() != 0x9AC6CDD7) {
            throw new BadElementException(errorID + " is not a valid placeable windows metafile.");
        }
```

The key point here might be "placeable".  I'm not exactly familiar with WMF, but you might be able to find an alternate `ImageFormat` or something.

Yep.  It looks like placeable WMFs are something Aldus came up with a while back.  Here's a question about converting from WMF to something iText can use:

http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/WMF-file-doesn-t-display-correctly-td2283480.html

This particular problem had to do with gradient fills.

Comment: I edited the above post and added the working solution code... not sure where the edit went.

Comment: @Clever I'd really like to learn about the working solution you posted. Do you stll have it somewhere?

Comment: I don't know where the original code that I posted went, but the solution was to realize that the chart control was producing and EMF file and not a WMF file, and that I needed to convert it. I had to use a Win32 Api call to do this: GdipEmfToWmfBits. Hope that helps!