# How to draw vector graphics and save it in PDF file?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project which generally is collecting data and drawing results in  charts. (Using C#) I need to save my charts in a PDF file. My question is, how to save charts in a PDF file without loosing resolution? My point is how to draw vector graphics instead of raster graphics?

I tried iTextSharp to create PDF file but the result is not satisfying at all!

I'm new here, so I'm not able to upload pictures.

Here is the result after saving my file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ruwtc82hfosxk6y/Test.pdf?dl=0

Here is the PDF that I need to create:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jvu5uu069imo9xc/nir%20well%20abfar.pdf?dl=0

Comment: I tried to create a pdf file using iTestSharp. To why it didn't work I need to show you my pdf files which my program has generated. Is there any way to upload pdf files?

Comment: If your charts are Chart controls you can try to save them as one of the `ChartImageFormat.Emf` formats. These __should__ be vector formats. Then look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935751/adding-a-wmf-to-a-pdf-using-itextsharp) for a solution how you can place them in a PDF..

Comment: So how do you create the chart? with a Chart control or with GDI-drawing? - Do you set the dpi resolution of the image before you use/insert/save it ? iTextSharp __ought__ to respect it; but: the default is only screen resolution; set it to at least 150 dpi.. But inserting a EMF image should be best..

Comment: I found that only wmf files can be inserted into a iTextSharp pdf. And as Chart only exports emf not wmf a converter emf -> wmf is needed. I used Illustrator and the result was excellten; but I couldn't find a free c# routine, so far..

Comment: @TaW: I create my charts with Chart control. I can't find the dpi property for iTextShartp! It's like there's no resolution settings! Would you please lead me to the best approach.

Comment: @TaW: Exactly! Is there any PDF generator (like iTextSharp) which accepts emf?    I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: I don't know. There is PDFSharp, but I don't know if it accepts EMF.

Comment: Here is the result from iTextSharp using an emf converted to wmf in Illustrator: [demo](http://www.file-upload.net/download-10636959/emfTest.pdf.html) - I can show you how to creae hi-res pngs from your chart; but I can't get iTextSharp to use their dpi resolution.. (May  be my fault..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I know of to get high-quality images from your `Chart` into a `PDF`.

**One** is by using vector formats:

- 1. Use `chart.SaveImage` with one of the three `emf` formats.
- 2. Convert the resulting `emf` file to `wmf`
- 3. Insert the `wmf` file into your `iTextSharp` document.

1 and 3 are one-liners. But step 2 is not. In fact I haven't found a working `c#` solution at all. The best was a weird reference to an edit that has disappeared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935751/adding-a-wmf-to-a-pdf-using-itextsharp) ..

If you can use some **other** program to do the conversion you will get nice results like [this demo pdf file](http://www.file-upload.net/download-10636959/emfTest.pdf.html).. I used **Illustrator** for the conversion.

**Two**: If you can't get step 2 to work, you can still get nice results, if you use raster images with a nice and **high resolution**. Here is how to do it:

First we hide the `Chart`, so we don't scare the user. Then we make it as large as we want the output to be. Then we `DrawToBitmap` and finally we reset the chart again..:

```
Size s = chart1.Size;
chart1.Hide();
// pick your size in pixels
// I simply multiply my screen size..:
chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(s.Width * 5, s.Height * 5);
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(chart1.ClientSize.Width, chart1.ClientSize.Height))
{
    // you should set the resolution, 
    // although I didn't find a way for iTextSharp to use it visually
    bmp.SetResolution(600, 600);
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        G.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        G.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        chart1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, chart1.ClientRectangle);
        bmp.Save(yourImageFile, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
chart1.Size = s;
chart1.Show();
```

You could also use SaveImage and save a few lines, but you can't set the resolution of the png file there and it will be saved at the currnt screen resolution, which is 96dpi here..

Now you have a large image and will probably have to scale it down in iTextSharp:

```
iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(yourImageFile);
img .ScalePercent(15);  // scale to fit your needs..
doc.Add(img );
```

Note that the legend and the labels get very small this way, so you may have to enlarge them before saving. I also found that, when scaling down, the image is rather bright until you zoom in..

Here are two screenshots, one from the chart, the other from the pdf documnet after zooming in a lot (300%)..:

[image] [image]

Comment: The result of the first approach is fantastic and exactly what I'm looking for. But as I'm not able to convert emf to wmf with c#, I should use the second approach. My problem has been solved in a way. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you found out how to convert emf to wmf, share it here, please.

Comment: You've been a lot of help, please accept my sincere gratitude.