# Is there any way to print MS chart on RDLC report document?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, rdlc, mschart

I've used MS chart in my application and I want to print that with few other information on paper; so that I've used RDLC.

I've tried converting chart in image and put it in image control of RDLC but it does not give sharpness when printed. **Sharpness is important in my case.**

Is there any way that utilize `chart.printing ...` method in combination with RDLC.

Comment: You can enlarge the chart for the purpose of creating a larger bitmap.

Comment: RDLC report has built-in chart support.

Comment: @TaW NO! Emf is not working with RDLC but in Crystal Report it does. But the print is not that good as we get with 'Chart.printing...' method

Comment: So can you define the resolution you think you need? (Something like 'output needs to be 4x2 inches at 300dpi')?

Comment: @TaW Finally I have opted the other way. Instead of using RDLC or Crystal. I've used `chart.printing..` with graphics object of printDocument event to print all the things with sharpness. It was urgent.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a file that with a 10 times better resolution:

```
chart.Hide();
Size oldsz = chart.ClientSize;

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(oldsz.Width * 10, oldsz.Height * 10);  // pick your factor    

chart.ClientSize = new Size(bmp .Width , bmp.Height);
chart.DrawToBitmap(bmp, chart.ClientRectangle);

bmp.SetResolution(300, 300);                     // pick your resolution
bmp.Save("D:\\xBigChart.png", ImageFormat.Png);  // png for crispiness

chart.ClientSize = oldsz;
chart.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks! but this doesn't help. It does not make image sharp.

Comment: __Yes it does make the chart a lot sharper.__ Explain what makes you think otherwise! It still is a bitmap, not a vector image, though. You can export vector formats via Chart.SaveImage, but they are not well-supported.

Comment: `You can export vertor formats via Chart.SaveImage, but they are not well-supported.` I didn't get this

Comment: Which part dodn't you get? Look at the supported formats (`ChartImageFormat`) and you will see three variations of  `Emf`.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002647/saving-charts-with-dynamic-view/32013687?s=1|0.1716#32013687) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411854/how-to-draw-vector-graphics-and-save-it-in-pdf-file/30414756?s=2|0.1030#30414756) for more!