# EMF-formatted memory streams for iTextSharp Image.GetInstance

Tags: c#, itext

I am using iTextSharp to stream images from my website into a PDF document. Specifically, I am using the Image.GetInstance(stream) method, bolded in the code snippet below. This method accepts a PNG memory stream and adds it to the PDF document without error, but seemingly does not accept an EMF memory stream. When I execute the code below using an EMF memory stream, I get the following exception: "The byte array is not a recognized imageformat."

Here is my C# code:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using IMG = iTextSharp.text.Image;

...

ImageType imgType = ImageType.EMF; //ImageType.PNG; 
using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = gm.CreateImageStream(null, imgType))
    {
        ms.Position = 0;
        IMG emf = IMG.GetInstance(ms);
        doc1.Add(emf);
    }
```

Do I need to modify the memory stream in some way in order to get an EMF formatted stream through the GetInstance method successfully?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4935751/231316) about creating it from a byte array instead of a stream? Also, [according to this very old thread](http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/WMF-file-doesn-t-display-correctly-td2283480.html), EMF might not be supported, only WMF.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it with this code.

```
var stream = imagePart.GetStream();

var image = Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream),

System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

image.ScalePercent(45);
```